# copying each instead of first unique data (div container's .sku div .html to image div's img attr ("src"))

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple DIVs, each containing a unique Product, each with it's own seperate class DIVS (image, product name, product price, and product sku).

I would like for each Product DIV to have its own image name matching the SKU. 
But instead it does the same first SKU it finds for every image! I hope this makes sense! I think I need to somehow apply an "each" or/and "this" somewhere...

Many Thanks if you can help!

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="product-box"><img class="product-img">
    <div class="product name">Geax 26" x 2.00 Cross Country Tyre Folding White</div>
    <div class="product price">£14.99</div><div class="product sku">112.3SG</div>
</div>

<div class="product-box"><img class="product-img">
    <div class="product name">Schwalbe Doc Blue Tubeless Sealant 60ML</div>
    <div class="product price">£5.99</div><div class="product sku">3710</div>
</div>

<div class="product-box"><img class="product-img">
    <div class="product name">Schwalbe Doc Blue Tubeless Sealant 500ML</div>
    <div class="product price">£15.99</div><div class="product sku">3711</div>
</div>
```

Here is the JQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var imagesrcname = $('.product.sku').html();
        $( ".product-img" ).attr("src","images/products/" + imagesrcname + ".jpg" );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `each`. Here's an example:

```
$('.product.sku').each(function( index ) {
   console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

make it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.product-box .sku').each( function(){
          var imagesrcname = $( this ).html();
          $( this ).parent().find( ".product-img" ).attr("src","images/products/" + imagesrcname + ".jpg" );
    } );
});
```

basically you need to iterate through all the product skus and take their individual image name (html inside the sku `div`) as `src` attribute to the `image`.

Comment: Thank you, you are Legendary!

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through images:

```
$(".product-img").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("src","images/products/" + $(this).siblings(".product.sku").html() + ".jpg");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but that script didn't seem to work

Comment: @BenjaminGoddard, Can't agree with you now. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/2g16exzs/
and try to inspect `src` attribute of any image